# How do I classify Linux process states as either running, runnable, not runnable or invalid?

Tags: linux, process

I need to classify the following process states (obtained from /proc/[PID]/status)

- R (running)
- S (sleeping)
- D (disk sleep)
- T (stopped)
- T (tracing stop)
- Z (zombie)
- X (dead)

as either

- running(1),
- runnable(2),    - waiting for resource (CPU, memory, IO)
- not runnable(3), - loaded but waiting for event
  or
- invalid(4)      - not loaded

My initial guess:

```
1:R (running)
2:S (sleeping)
3:D (disk sleep)
3:T (stopped)
3:T (tracing stop)
4:Z (zombie)
4:X (dead)
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Tag questions with `Homework` if they are such.

Answer (score 0):

From fs/proc/array.c:

```
static const char * const task_state_array[] = {
        "R (running)",          /*   0 */
        "S (sleeping)",         /*   1 */
        "D (disk sleep)",       /*   2 */
        "T (stopped)",          /*   4 */
        "t (tracing stop)",     /*   8 */
        "Z (zombie)",           /*  16 */
        "X (dead)",             /*  32 */
        "x (dead)",             /*  64 */
        "K (wakekill)",         /* 128 */       
        "W (waking)",           /* 256 */
};
```

Comment: This did not answer the question at all, you are just pasting the list of task states and what their integer equivalent is.

The original question wanted to group the states into four categories he specified as 1-4